# Updating Div with Total Records Outside of table

Tags: javascript, datatables

I’m working with datatables and trying to figure out what I’m doing wrong. I am trying to display the total number of rows when the table hits the draw event on the table. Right now with the code, I’m showing below I am not getting any console errors. The element where the number is supposed to be updated is correct. I am just not getting it to render with the correct count.

```
("use strict");

const renderStatusCell = (data, type, full, meta) => {
    const status = {
        0: { title: "Inactive" },
        1: { title: "Active" }
    };
    if (typeof status[data] === "undefined") {
        return data;
    }
    return status[data].title;
};

var table = $('[data-table="users.index"]');

// begin first table
table.DataTable({
    // Order settings
    order: [[1, "desc"]],
    ajax: "/titles",
    columns: [
        { data: "id", title: "User ID" },
        { data: "name", title: "Name" },
        { data: "slug", title: "Slug" },
        { data: "introduced_at", title: "Date Introduced" },
        { data: "is_active", title: "Status", render: renderStatusCell },
        {
            data: "action",
            title: "Actions",
            orderable: false,
            responsivePriority: -1
        }
    ]
});

var updateTotal = function() {
    table.on("draw", function() {
        $("#kt_subheader_total").html(table.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal());
    });
};
```

I expected when the table was rendered to update the dom with the correct number of rows however the div does not get updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your problem, but I think you need something like that.

```
table
.row($(this).parents('tr'))
.remove()
.draw();
```

or

```
table.ajax.reload();
```

Comment: The problem is that I am storing the total of how many rows outside of the normal datatables flow.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to wait until the HTML loads before running all your javascript code. Also, if you are storing the total, you not make it a function but rather just store the value.

```
'use strict';

// this will make sure all the HTML loads before the JavaScript runs.
$(function() {
  var table = $('[data-table="users.index"]');
  var updateTotal = null; // store in a variable

  const renderStatusCell = (data, type, full, meta) => {
    const status = {
      0: { title: "Inactive" },
      1: { title: "Active" }
    };

    if (typeof status[data] === "undefined")
        return data;

    return status[data].title;
  };

  // begin first table
  table.DataTable({
    // Order settings
    order: [[1, "desc"]],
    ajax: "/titles",
    columns: [
      { data: "id", title: "User ID" },
      { data: "name", title: "Name" },
      { data: "slug", title: "Slug" },
      { data: "introduced_at", title: "Date Introduced" },
      { data: "is_active", title: "Status", render: renderStatusCell },
      {
        data: "action",
        title: "Actions",
        orderable: false,
        responsivePriority: -1
      }
    ]
  });

  table.on("draw", function() {
    updateTotal = table.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal();
    $("#kt_subheader_total").html(table.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal());
  });
});
```

Comment: My javascript works fine as is so it doesn't require to wait for the HTML to load. The only problem is that the dom element doesn't update when its supposed to.

Comment: Have you tried to reload the data in? https://www.meadow.se/wordpress/refreshing-data-in-jquery-datatables/